# Different sessionID after server restart express

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I've noticed noticed that when I restart my Express server, the session id saved on the browser is updated to a new value. Is this normal behavior?
 Is this something I can configure?

These are my current `express-session` options:

```
var sessionOptions = {
  secret: "secret_here",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 86400000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session):

> Each session has a unique ID associated with it.

You can override the function that generates the ID by setting the genid property.

```
app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return genuuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}))
```

Comment: But why does it create a new session when the server is **restarted**? That is my question.